# Docker network live reload node/angular app

Tags: angular, docker, express, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm still new to docker and currently experimenting with creating a development environment. I've also created a docker network to add the three service. I have:

- An angular app
- An express app
- A mongodb image

My docker files are as follows:

Dockerfile for express app

```js
FROM node:12.0.0

ENV PORT=3000

COPY . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN npm install

EXPOSE $PORT

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "start.dev"]
```

Dockerfile for angular app

```js
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:12.0.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./


# COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

CMD npm start
```

docker-compose.yml

```js
version: '3'

services:

  express-app:
    build:
      context: ./auth-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - docker-network

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    networks:
      - docker-network

  angular-app:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - "/frontend/node_modules"
      - ".:/frontend"
    networks:
      - docker-network

networks:
  docker-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Angular app package.json

```js
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Express app package.json

```js
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start.dev": "nodemon -L src/app.ts"
  },
```

docker logs for angular container
[image]

docker logs for express container
[image]

When running "docker compose build" and "docker compose up", there's not errors. But hot reloading is not working when modifying the source code.

I have tried the angular app by creating a docker volume and the express app does not have a docker volume.

Can you please help?

Thank you.

Comment: Any luck in finding the solution?

Comment: @Devashish I did it locally for the node and angular app. Started mongodb on docker and link the url in node app.

Answer (score 0):

**It would most likely be advisable to update your question with the log files for both your containers, that will help people to assist further if the logs give a specific angular error.**

If it is related to specific Angular setup (folder/configurations etc) some other users may be able to advise further.

*Without log files it will be really hard for people to assist.*

This will be a list for guiding/troubleshooting Docker configuration, and most likely will not end up as a concrete answer related to your issue.  I advise on basic usage of some docker-compose and docker commands (so some of these you might have already tried).

1. When you say 'hot reloading', do you mean you compiler angular app, or trying to reload the Docker containers?
   There is a difference between `docker-compose down/up` and `docker-compose stop/start`.   As you know `up` creates the containers, so care not to try to use `down` because it will delete containers. Start/stop with other commands.
2. The first place to start to see is to see the logs for the currently created containers:    - `docker logs container_name1`
   *(By default docker-compose appends the current folder name where the docker-compose.yml file is located as part of the new container names)*.
   See `docker-compose ps` (you use it in the docker-compose.yml or subfolders) to see created container names for this instance and statuses.
3. Ports might be blocked by a firewall, so take care of that and open accordingly for your OS.  Make sure the ports shown by `docker-compose ps` actually show `port 3000, 4200`.
4. Your volumes seem to be a *new empty unnamed volume* `/frontend/node_modules` and a *bind mount* taking the current context ie : ./frontend and mounts it to `/frontend`.  Was that your intention?

   I have no real knowledge of angular, but is `node_modules` supposed to be empty in the new container?  Are you planning to add/install node modules inside the container once the apps are running?  This is useful only until you want to rebuild the images.  Once you have tested your containers further, *make a note of the modules you want to install and try to make Dockerfile `RUN` commands for the corresponding installation of modules.  This would also most likely mean your **node_modules** content should be be Dockerfile `ADD`ed instead of creating a volume for them.   *I assume package.json contains descriptions of the modules to be installed once inside the container?*

   Your persistent app data that you want to externally/internally maintain with your bind-mount I think is setup correctly (accessed at `/frontend` it seems).
5. If your apps are running correctly before you 'hot-restart', have you accessed the created containers to see the content and see if folder locations/logs etc look correct?   Run `docker exec -ti container_name bash` (Ubuntu container as example) and navigate inside.

Comment: Hello @CvRChameleon, thank you for your response. I have added the logs in the question.

When I'm saying "hot reloading", I mean that, when I'm changing the codes in my IDE, I would like to see the changes reflected on my browser. I've done some research and saw that it was possible but it seems to not work for me.

Sorry if the question was not clear enough and please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Regarding your 4th point, I think that I still don't have a good understanding of volumes, I'm currently going through the documentation again. Thank you for this heads up.

Comment: I imagine it should be possible to be able to refresh once your **bind-mounts** are setup correctly, and there is no cache getting in the way (server/browser).  I have used bind-mounts with a few web projects (not angular of course).

Comment: ok, thank you for the pointers. I'll look into this and reply here after trying out some things related to this. Have you ever tried with node/express projects?

Comment: Please confirm your container names, as you are accessing container `82` and `df`, but your `docker-compose.yml` they are called `express-app` and `angular-app`.  Technically `docker-compose up` names should be created like `currentfolder_express-app` and `currentfolder_angular-app` (version 3+).  For your info, current versions of docker-compose you can update your 'version' to 3.7 (there is 3.8 but it seems to be slightly different)

Comment: @Aeonify, only in a non-docker environment and not really be able to assist there...

Comment: Side question: Are you able to access your website as soon as you create the containers, immediately before you want to apply edits from your editor

Comment: Please give me 1 hour, I'll go through the docker configurations again to make sure that I'm not being confused and I'll update the question with the exact steps I've done so that you can have a better idea of how you can help me. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Good luck!  Docker configurations are confusing when starting out, and official documentation is not the best.